# Rails 3.1 application.css updates don't affect webpage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm using Rails 3.1. I'm starting to have a problem -- any time I update my application.css it doesn't update the CSS of the webpage I'm working on. The server seems to be fetching an old version of the CSS instead of keeping up with the changes I make in my application. What are some possible reasons and solutions for this? Does it perhaps have to do with precompilation? (By the way I'm of course doing this all on my local machine.)

I'm sorry but I can't really tell when this started happening - which would be useful. I had been working on other parts and came back to this a few weeks later to find out that the application.css file wasn't affecting any changes.

By the way, I haven't changed

```
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
```

... it's still there in my application. Also, in-line CSS still works, which is why I know it's a problem with the application.css.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go into your public folder and delete the assets folder. When you deployed (or did a push) it precompiled your assets.

Answer (score 0):

Show as your Source Page or Log.
Try:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag :application %>
```

And tell where you have application.sass or application.scss

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I have <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %> in the <head> tags of my application.html.erb if that's what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Go to tmp > cache 
Delete assets folder

Only solution that worked for me